# Using Selenium, xpath gets tags but text is empty

Tags: selenium

I'm using Selenium WebDriver to fetch a bunch of tags via XPATH. The xpath successfully finds the tags, but the "Text" attribute for the returned IWebElements is empty.

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul>
<li id="foo1">someValue</li>
<li id="foo2">someOtherValue</li>
</ul>
```

And the xpath:

```
//ul/li[startswith(@id, 'foo')]
```

Any ideas? The Xpath definitely grabs the right elements, but the Text element is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code to get the text of 2nd element - `<li id="foo2">someOtherValue</li>`
:

```
WebElement fooEle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//descendant::ul/li[starts-with(@id,'foo')][2]"));
String fooEleText = fooEle.getText();
System.out.println("foo Element Text -" + fooEleText); //should print expected text "someOtherValue"
```

Note- if you want to get the 1st element text, then change the index value of the xpath
That is, `//descendant::ul/li[starts-with(@id,'foo')][1]`

Comment: What is the function of the "descendant::" prefix?

Comment: It is a XPATH axis. The 'descendant' axis contains the descendants of the context node; a descendant is a child or a child of a child and so on;

Comment: I tried it out, and while it does effectively grab the whole axis, the text element is still empty for the <li> IWebElement instances. Any ideas?

Comment: Check whether below xpath finds required <li>: //li[text()='someOtherValue' ; Just to ensure we are trying to access required li.

Comment: It definitely finds the <li> tags. However the IWebElement instances have empty Text values.

Comment: Aha! Figured it out. The problem is that the <ul> I'm dealing with is a dojo-style dropdown. The Text contents reflect *visible* text of each <li>, so you have to FIRST select the dropdown, THEN grab the <li> contents. Wow.